# Property does not exist on type with union types

Tags: typescript

I've got a type that's trying to describe a serialisable deep nested "plain javascript" object:

```
export interface MappingReferenceValues {
  /** The reference values */
  [key: string]:
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | MappingReferenceValues
    | string[]
    | number[]
    | boolean[]
    | MappingReferenceValues[];
}
```

It lets me define simple deep nestesd key value pairs of numbers, strings, booleans, or their arrays:

```
const thing: MappingReferenceValues = {
  test: {
    test2: {
      test3: "hi",
      test4: 200,
      test5: [true, false]
    }
  }
};
```

Great! Works fine for declaring it. It's much better than `any`, because it ensures I've not got functions in there, and it's distinct from `undefined`.

However, it's a real pain to use:

```
const output = thing.test.test2.test3
```

Comes up with an error:

```
Property 'test2' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | MappingReferenceValues | string[] | number[] | boolean[] | MappingReferenceValues[]'.
  Property 'test2' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

`test2` doesn't exist on type string, but it does exist on type `MappingReferenceValues`. Is there any way around this without just casting it to any again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is valid for the interface you defined.

If you receive serialized value of `MappingReferenceValues` type and deserialize it, how do you know that there is `test2` nested property on it?

*It is more logical in the example which uses `MappingReferenceValues` as input parameter of a function:*

```js
function parse(value: MappingReferenceValues) {
    value./* We don't know keys, nor types after the dot */
}
```

If you need to manipulate variable `thing` that you just created further then omit type definition. You can still pass it to a function that expects `MappingReferenceValues` type.

```js
function parse(value: MappingReferenceValues) {
    /* TODO */
}

const thing = {
    test: {
        test2: {
            test3: "hi",
            test4: 200,
            test5: [true, false]
        }
    }
};

const output = thing.test.test2.test3; // working

parse(thing); // also working;
```

Comment: It's interesting, because you say "how do you know that there is test2 nested property on it?", but I could equally ask, how do I know there's a `test` property on it? The `[key: string]` says that there could be any string properties - but there might not be one called `test`, or even any at all. It seems inconsistent. Similarly, it assumes it's a string. So I could do `thing.test.trim()`, even though it could be a nested object.

Comment: You defined that there can be a key of any name on the root object. It can be `test` or, for example, `random`. Try line `const output = thing.random.test2.test3` and you will get exactly same error as with `test` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
const thing: MappingReferenceValues = {
  test: {
    test2: {
      test3: "hi",
      test4: 200,
      test5: [true, false]
    }
  },
  newTest: [2]
};
```

You need to differentiate between `thing.test` and `thing.newTest`.

By definition of `MappingReferenceValues`, thing can contain any `string` key, so all of these access are fine:

```
let test = thing.test;
let newTest = thing.newTest;
let newTest2 = thing.newTest2; // still 'newTest2' does't not exits on thing.
```

Now check type of `test`, `newTest`, `newTest2`. They all can be any of `string | number | boolean | string[] | MappingReferenceValues | number[] | boolean[] | MappingReferenceValues[]`;

So to access its values like `test.field` first you need to narrow its type to `MappingReferenceValues`.

This narrowing can be done with

```
function isMappingReferneceValues(a: unknown): a is MappingReferenceValues {
  ...
  return true;
}
```